# Python boto generate_url with plus symbols in url

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am using python boto library to upload images to s3. But previously few images are uploaded manually to bucket which contains + in urls.
     
     `k = Key(bucket)
     k.key = 'a+b_Q1.jpg'
     k.set_metadata('Content-Type', mime)
     url = k.generate_url(expires_in=0, query_auth=False,encrypt_key=False)`

so e.g.:

- s3old url -> `mybuckect/a+b.jpg`
- boto_generate_url - `mybucket/a%Bb_Q1.jpg`
- what i am expecting is `mybucket/a+b_Q1.jpg`

I really don't want generate_url to encode my URL. How do I override this?